# Render selected object only while moving, scaling and rotating

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, photos

I am currently working on a "Photo Collage Maker" project which needs larger canvas area and hundreds of objects(text, images, shapes, clip-arts etc.). The problem is while moving, scaling and rotating those objects, Fabric.js render all the objects which makes it too slow. I want to render only the selected objects on top of the fabric canvas. I have tested renderOnAddition, renderTop also but they are not what I want.

I want the following:

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
    var activeObject = e.target;
    //canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.renderObjects(activeObject);
});
```

Now instead of `canvas.renderAll()`, I need method like `canvas.renderObjects(activeObject)`. How can I achieve this functionality in Fabric.js?

Here is my project : [Edit Photos For Free](http://editphotosforfree.com)

Comment: You must render all, there is no other way. It doesn't metter state of which object had changed, the drawing proccess is drawing pixels. Like frames in a digital video, even if it is a static picture, there are still 25 frames ...

Comment: If it's not possible, for the sake of fabricjs performance, how can i implement cacheAsBitmap property so that only the moving part is rendered and all other static parts are cached as bitmap. Any ideas and algorithm to implement this on fabricjs ?

Comment: sorry, can't help here. good luck

Comment: This comment is possibly related to what you want to do:

https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/318

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to have a second canvas, in front of the main one, on which you move/scale/rotate the current item(s).

You mention wanting to render the selected objects on top of the fabric canvas, so this should meet your requirements.

On ending the move/scale/rotate you will have to restore the original canvas elements, apply your changes, and allow it to do a full redraw.

Answer (score 0):

May be there are many renderAll() methods

Chech if that is case you need to use requestRenderAll() method